# .NET FirebirdClient.FbException (0x80004005): Your user name and password are not defined

Tags: c#, ado.net, firebird

My c# service tries to connect to the remote host and failing all the time, but Flamerobin with same credentials working fine, also I can connect to this server over firebird isql tool.

Version of my Firebird ADO.net provider is 5.8.0

The service works fine with other clients (with other db servers), so I think that problem in Firebird version on the current server or some network problems.

On the server we have windows and Firebird 3.0.3 with Legacy_Auth is On, and users are created as legasy.

```
SYSDBA                          Legacy_UserManager             
CHEA                            Legacy_UserManager             
SYSDBA                          Srp
```

I try different connectionStrings, like

```
connectionString="User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=bd;DataSource=10.0.0.56;Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=WIN1251;"
```

or

```
connectionString="User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=/info/bd.fdb;DataSource=10.0.0.56;Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=WIN1251;"
```

all this way work in flamerobin and not work in .net service. Service return error:

> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException (0x80004005): Your username and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login. ---> Your username and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.
>      в FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect() в C:\Users\Jiri\Documents\devel\NETProvider\working\Provider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\FirebirdClient\FbConnectionInternal.cs:строка 172
>      в FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPoolManager.Pool.CreateNewConnectionIfPossibleImpl(FbConnectionString connectionString) в C:\Users\Jiri\Documents\devel\NETProvider\working\Provider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\FirebirdClient\FbConnectionPoolManager.cs:строка 195
>      в FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPoolManager.Pool.GetConnection(FbConnection owner) в C:\Users\Jiri\Documents\devel\NETProvider\working\Provider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\FirebirdClient\FbConnectionPoolManager.cs:строка 99
>      в FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open() в C:\Users\Jiri\Documents\devel\NETProvider\working\Provider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\FirebirdClient\FbConnection.cs:строка 516

I lost a couple days trying to solve the problem, can you help me?

Can it be some FirebirdClient version collision, or something else?

Comment: `Charset=WIN1251;`  hmmm....   ---> http://sql.ru/forum/interbase

Comment: in Firebird 3 there are potentially two SYSDBA users - the Legacy one and the new "SRP" one. You have to create BOTH after FB3 installation, if you (your apps) need them. Check release notes and other documentation about installing and configuring fb3. There even was a book about migrating to FB3. Try `select * from sec$users`. It seems you did not created one of those two SYSDBAs and that makes .Net provider fail. Also try http://www.ibprovider.com - commercial, but maybe it would make it have better support

Comment: I add description, in db i have users both types, also i try to connect via CHEA user - same error

Comment: Which version of the Firebird ADO.net provider are you using?

Comment: Mark Rottevee, i use 5.8.0 version of Firebird ADO.NETdata provider and same EntityFramework.Firebird